# Java socket Json

Tags: java, json, multithreading, sockets

**UPDATED**

There is my updated code after the response,
I have one problem, now, i didn't receive anything :

**Problem** :

```
Connexion cliente reçue.
Lancement du traitement de la connexion cliente
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cuisine.TimeServer.onResponseReceived(TimeServer.java:85)
    at cuisine.ClientProcessor.run(ClientProcessor.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

TimeServer: 85 : Callback

```
  @Override
  public void onResponseReceived(String response) {
    // When the response is received from ClientProcessor
    // this method is called (by ClientProcessor).
    // Your response is the parameter String response.
    callback.onResponse(response);
  }
```

Client processor: 43 :

```
server.onResponseReceived(response);
```

One client can connect but i can't receive anything : Json or text.

There is my new Java Code :

**Main.java :**

```
   import cuisine.TimeServer.OnResponseReceivedListener;


public class main implements OnResponseReceivedListener {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String host = "192.168.1.21";
        int port = 8080;

        TimeServer ts = new TimeServer(host, port);
        ts.open();
        System.out.println("------------Connected ! ------------");

   }

   @Override
   public void onResponse(String response) {
     doSomethingWith(response);
     System.out.println("REPONSE : ");
     System.out.println(response);

   }

   private void doSomethingWith(String response) {
         System.out.println("REPONSE : ");
         System.out.println(response);
   }


}
```

I don't really know how to use the response now, because the sysout "RESPONSE" is not in my console
**TimeServer.java :**

```
...
import cuisine.ClientProcessor.Server;


public class TimeServer implements Server {

  public interface OnResponseReceivedListener {
    void onResponse(String response);
  }

  private int port = 2345;
  private String host = "127.0.0.1";
  private ServerSocket server = null;
  private boolean isRunning = true;
  private OnResponseReceivedListener callback;

  public TimeServer() {
    try {
      server = new ServerSocket(port, 100, InetAddress.getByName(host));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public TimeServer(String pHost, int pPort) {
    host = pHost;
    port = pPort;
    try {
      server = new ServerSocket(port, 100, InetAddress.getByName(host));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void open() {

    Thread t =
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                while (isRunning == true) {

                  try {
                    Socket client = server.accept();

                    System.out.println("Connexion cliente reçue.");
                    ClientProcessor c = new ClientProcessor(client);
                    Thread t = new Thread(c);
                    // Don't forget to define the Server for ClientProcessor
                    c.addServer(TimeServer.this);
                    t.start();

                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }

                try {
                  server.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  server = null;
                }
              }
            });

    t.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponseReceived(String response) {
    // When the response is received from ClientProcessor
    // this method is called (by ClientProcessor).
    // Your response is the parameter String response.
    callback.onResponse(response);
  }

  public void addOnResponseReceivedListener(OnResponseReceivedListener listener) {
    callback = listener;
  }

  public void removeOnResponseReceivedListener() {
    callback = null;
  }

  public void close() {
    isRunning = false;
  }
}
```

**ClientProcessor.java :**

```
public class ClientProcessor implements Runnable {

      public interface Server {
        void onResponseReceived(String response);
      }

      private Socket sock;
      private PrintWriter writer = null;
      private BufferedInputStream reader = null;
      public List<Dish> dish;
      // Your server instance
      private Server server;

      public ClientProcessor(Socket pSock) {
        this.sock = pSock;
      }

      public void run() {
        System.err.println("Lancement du traitement de la connexion cliente");

        boolean closeConnexion = false;
        while (!sock.isClosed()) {

          try {

            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            reader = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

            String response = read();

            // report the response to TimeServer
            server.onResponseReceived(response);

            InetSocketAddress remote = (InetSocketAddress) sock.getRemoteSocketAddress();

            String debug = "";
            debug = "Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". ";
            debug += "Demande de l'adresse : " + remote.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ".";
            debug += " Sur le port : " + remote.getPort() + ".\n";
            debug += "\t -> Commande reçue : " + response + "\n";
            System.err.println("\n" + debug);

            String toSend = "";

            switch (response.toUpperCase()) {
              case "ORDER":
                toSend = "Dish";
                break;
              case "CLOSE":
                toSend = "Communication terminée";
                closeConnexion = true;
                break;
              default:
                toSend = "Commande inconnu !";
                break;
            }

            writer.write(toSend);
            writer.flush();

            if (closeConnexion) {
              System.err.println("COMMANDE CLOSE DETECTEE ! ");
              writer = null;
              reader = null;
              sock.close();
              break;
            }
          } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.err.println("LA CONNEXION A ETE INTERROMPUE ! ");
            break;
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }

      public void addServer(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
      }

      private void removeServer() {
        server = null;
      }

      // La méthode que nous utilisons pour lire les réponses
      private String read() throws IOException {
        String response = "";
        int stream;
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        stream = reader.read(b);
        response = new String(b, 0, stream);
        return response;
      }
    }
```

Thanks,
Benjamin.

Comment: What is your question here @Benjamin?

Comment: @Skemelio I want to be able to use the response(JSON receive) in my main

Comment: Are you receiving the JSON response?

Comment: Because if you do then this question should be about Json manipulation and not sockets.

Comment: @Skemelio I receive response, not json for the moment i don't know how to do,

Comment: And after i need to manipulate this json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (updated Main.java)

**Update No2** (Removed static methods from `Main.java` and use a `Main` object)

**Edit:** (removed previous answer about sockets)

> This is the json response, now i want to use it in my main : on
>   another class in the same package.

Since you've stated that **you are getting a response** from client but  you don't know how to manipulate it in your `Main` class then your issue is not about sockets.

A solution: Use **callbacks**:

- `ClientProcessor` will report the response to `TimeServer`.
- `TimeServer` will report that response to `Main`.

Make `ClientProcessor` aware of the server and report when the response is fetched.

```
public class ClientProcessor implements Runnable {

  public interface Server {
    void onResponseReceived(String response);
  }

  private Socket sock;
  private PrintWriter writer = null;
  private BufferedInputStream reader = null;
  public List<Dish> dish;
  // Your server instance
  private Server server;

  public ClientProcessor(Socket pSock) {
    this.sock = pSock;
  }

  public void run() {
    System.err.println("Lancement du traitement de la connexion cliente");

    boolean closeConnexion = false;
    while (!sock.isClosed()) {

      try {

        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        reader = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        String response = read();

        // report the response to TimeServer
        server.onResponseReceived(response);

        InetSocketAddress remote = (InetSocketAddress) sock.getRemoteSocketAddress();

        String debug = "";
        debug = "Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". ";
        debug += "Demande de l'adresse : " + remote.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ".";
        debug += " Sur le port : " + remote.getPort() + ".\n";
        debug += "\t -> Commande reçue : " + response + "\n";
        System.err.println("\n" + debug);

        String toSend = "";

        switch (response.toUpperCase()) {
          case "ORDER":
            toSend = "Dish";
            break;
          case "CLOSE":
            toSend = "Communication terminée";
            closeConnexion = true;
            break;
          default:
            toSend = "Commande inconnu !";
            break;
        }

        writer.write(toSend);
        writer.flush();

        if (closeConnexion) {
          System.err.println("COMMANDE CLOSE DETECTEE ! ");
          writer = null;
          reader = null;
          sock.close();
          break;
        }
      } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.err.println("LA CONNEXION A ETE INTERROMPUE ! ");
        break;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private void addServer(Server server) {
    this.server = server;
  }

  private void removeServer() {
    server = null;
  }

  // La méthode que nous utilisons pour lire les réponses
  private String read() throws IOException {
    String response = "";
    int stream;
    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    stream = reader.read(b);
    response = new String(b, 0, stream);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Now go to `TimeServer` and make it aware of `Main` (same procedure as before). You must also need to report the response to `Main` when its being received from `ClientProcessor`.

```
public class TimeServer implements Server {

  public interface OnResponseReceivedListener {
    void onResponse(String response);
  }

  private int port = 2345;
  private String host = "127.0.0.1";
  private ServerSocket server = null;
  private boolean isRunning = true;
  private OnResponseReceivedListener callback;

  public TimeServer() {
    try {
      server = new ServerSocket(port, 100, InetAddress.getByName(host));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public TimeServer(String pHost, int pPort) {
    host = pHost;
    port = pPort;
    try {
      server = new ServerSocket(port, 100, InetAddress.getByName(host));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void open() {

    Thread t =
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                while (isRunning == true) {

                  try {
                    Socket client = server.accept();

                    System.out.println("Connexion cliente reçue.");
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ClientProcessor(client));
                    // Don't forget to define the Server for ClientProcessor
                    t.addServer(TimeServer.this);
                    t.start();

                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }

                try {
                  server.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  server = null;
                }
              }
            });

    t.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponseReceived(String response) {
    // When the response is received from ClientProcessor
    // this method is called (by ClientProcessor).
    // Your response is the parameter String response.
    callback.onResponse(response);
  }

  public void addOnResponseReceivedListener(OnResponseReceivedListener listener) {
    callback = listener;
  }

  public void removeOnResponseReceivedListener() {
    callback = null;
  }

  public void close() {
    isRunning = false;
  }
}
```

Finaly, make your `Main` to listen to `TimeServer` and do something when it receives the response.

```
public class Main implements OnResponseReceivedListener {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main application = new Main();
    TimeServer ts = application.createTimeServer();
    ts.addOnResponseReceivedListener(application);
    ts.open();
    System.out.println("------------Connected ! ------------");
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {
    doSomethingWith(response);
  }

  private void doSomethingWith(String response) {
    // Your logic for the response here...
  }

  private TimeServer createTimeServer() {
    String host = "192.168.43.178";
    int port = 8080;
    return new TimeServer(host, port);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
but when i try this code

i have one error  = readLine doesn't exist : reader.readLine())

for the ps  : I don't know for the moment how to receive json in my server 
But i am sure that the Json send by the client is correct

Comment: Hello Benji, my bad. I thought you were using `BufferedReader` but you use `BufferedInputStream`, so yes you need the buffers and yes there is no `readLine()`.

Comment: I will edit the answer and you can give it a try if you want.

Comment: When i connect my client to my server i receive JSON :
  -> Commande reçue : {"Table":{"Capacity":5,"IsAvailable":true,"isDressed":true,"Customers":null},"Recipes":[{"Price":10.0,"RecipeName":"chocolat","Category":"dessert"}]}

Comment: This is the json response, now i want to use it in my main : on another class in the same package, thanks for u time@Skemelio

Comment: Ok, so your question has nothing to do with sockets. You receive the response correctly and just want to use it on your Main. Right?

Comment: Yes @skemelio,   sorry

Comment: One last question and I will write another answer. How many clients do you want to accept? One or many?

Comment: There is just one client

Comment: I updated my post : I have one problem, now, i didn't receive anything i just got an error : Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException ...... (in the updated post) @ Skemelio

Comment: This code should throw a compile error because the file `Main.java` defines a class that its name is `main`.

Comment: But anyway I know the problem, I forgot something, I will update the answer. By the way don't forget to mark the answer as correct if you think it is...

Comment: Sure i will mark @Skemelio, i have a problem with the listener "this" in the main : the program return an error :  Cannot use this in a static context

Comment: Yeah don't actually use `Main` class apart from the `main()` function. I will make update `Main.java`.